# Grouping in select query returns more rows than in actual selecting table?

Tags: sql, grouping

I need to select few columns from table which contains 10 records, I need to group these 1 records by `productId`.
If I group all these records from product table which contains more than 120 records am getting more than 1000 records.

Comment: Edit your question and show your query.  You cannot get more rows using `group by` than in the original data.

Comment: Are you doing any JOINs? Cartesian Product between your two tables would be more than 1200 records.

Comment: My crystal call says: `Cartesian Product`.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are not using the JOIN correctly.  You need to say where the two (or more) tables have a value which is equal. Such as....

```
SELECT COUNT(a.AppleId) as AppleAmt, b.BasketLocation, c.ContainerColor
FROM Apples as a INNER JOIN
Baskets as b ON a.BasketId = b.BasketId INNER JOIN
Containers as c ON b.ContainerId = c.ContainerId
WHERE a.Rotten IS NULL and a.Eaten IS NULL and a.SoTasty IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.BasketLocation, c.ContainerColor
ORDER BY b.BasketLocation DESC
```